# regex match number

Tags: regex

I need a regex (JavaScript) to match 2, 23 and not include 37 in the following case.

```
[B.TARGET.avg(37)]*2 + length(23)
```

Comment: there is no difference between `23` and `37` as far as they both contain 2 digits.

Comment: difference is 37 is inside []

Comment: The simple way is to replace `\[.*?\]` with nothing. Then use `\d+` on whats left. Otherwise, it's a complicated task.

Comment: Yes, I know it is complicated, but I cannot replace the text because it will confuse my existing parser logics. I have been working on it for last two hours. but still no idea. Anyone could help?

Comment: If you don't want to do it simple, you have to match the `[]` to move the position past it. That ends up being  `\[.*?\]|(\d+)` Now for each match you have to check if capture buffer 1 contains anything.

Comment: hi sln, your regex \[.*?\]|(\d+) match everything inside [], is there a way to exclude them from results?

Comment: Please consider providing better sample-data and regex you already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match outside brackets if between, you need to [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), if there's not a closing `]`

```
var re = /\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?![^[]*?\])/g;
```

- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` matches one or more digits (optional point number)
- `(?![^[]*?\])` looks ahead, if there is not [non](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)-opening brackets, followed by a closing `]`

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iV0xP1/2)

---

The positive lookahead option would be to check if there is only balanced brackets ahead:

```
var re = /\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=(?:[^[\]]*\[[^[\]]*\])*[^[\]]*$)/g;
```

`(?=(?:[^[\]]*\[[^[\]]*\])*[^[\]]*$)` looks ahead for an even amount of brackets.

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aS7uG1/1)

Comment: Wrong approach. This won't let a digit match anytime a `]` is downstream. None of these 23,54 [sdfas] will match.

Comment: in this case, nothing is matched. [B.TARGET.avg(375)]*233 + length(233) + 2323.23 + [C(23)]

Comment: @Jackie put code into backticks `like this` or it'll be hard to read

Comment: @Jackie see updated answer. sln thanks - yes, it was for input where there is no square brackets ahead.